# Creating unique invite codes and tracking who used it

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to see if the way that I implemented the creation of unique invitation codes works. My database is Firestore and I have a collection called inviteCodes where each document is an invitation code with fields tracking who created the code and who used the code. There shouldn't be any duplicate invitation code in the collection...so I wanted to see if the way I implemented invite code generation works. Basically I have a while loop that keeps generating a new code until it cannot find a document in Firestore with the the same code.

Just wanted to make sure that this isn't going to be an infinite loop making a ton of calls to Firestore...thanks!

```
String code = getRandomString(6);
    var docExist = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('inviteCodes')
        .doc(code)
        .get();
    while (docExist.exists == true) {
      code = getRandomString(6);
      docExist = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('inviteCodes')
          .doc(code)
          .get();
    }
    Map<String, dynamic> codeGeneration() {
      return {
        'user': myUser.userID,
        'usedBy': usedBy,
        'code': code,
      };
    }

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('inviteCodes')
        .doc(code)
        .set(codeGeneration());
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use the document id that Firestore gives when a new document is added to `inviteCodes` collection?

Comment: Mainly because document ids are extremely long and hard for users to remember

Comment: I see, I thought you are using this to send out a link or something like that. Your solution will do what you want and if you don't create thousands of invite codes chances are pretty low that you will perform many queries.